# Como alterar valores abreviados em um DF usando Pandas no Python

Tags: python, pandas, data, dataframe

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um df com mais de 50 colunas, nessas colunas, algumas tem valor do tipo "35,57B", "6,85T".Como faço para fazer de forma iterativa e substituir os exemplos citados anteriormente para que fiquem do seguinte modo "3557000000","6850000000000"?

[image: Exemplo de como é o DF]

Tentei algo do tipo

```
for col in df:
    df.col = (df.col.replace(r'[KMBT]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * df.col.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KMBT]+)', expand=False).fillna(1).replace(['K','M','B','T'], [10**3, 10**6, 10**9, 10**12]).astype(int))
```

Porém não obtive sucesso, e teve o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
```

Obrigado pelas respostas com elas foi possível elaborar a solução. Que foi a seguinte:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:    
    df[col] = (df[col].str.replace(',','.').replace('N/A','0').replace(r'[kMBT%]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * df[col].str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([kMBT%]+)', expand=False).fillna(1).replace(['k','M','B','T',"%"], [10**3, 10**6, 10**9, 10**12,1]).astype(float))
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('.',',')
```

Comment: Pode fornecer um dataset de exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é definir uma função, usar list comprehension e iterar sobre `df.columns`:

```py
def transform_str(value:str):
    return value.replace(",","").replace("B","000000").replace("T","0000000000")

for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=[transform_str(k) for k in df[col]]
```

Comment: Boa tarde!
Então a sua solução gera o seguinte output 3562000000, 6850000000000 só que os valores são por exemplo 35,63B e 6,87T, os dados não estão todos no mesmo formato, tem dados como "48,1B". Por esse motivo eu estava procurando algo que multiplicasse o valor existente por exemplo substituindo o "B" por "10**9". Mas muito obrigado me deu um insight de como solucionar!

Comment: Entendi. Mas esses foram os exemplos que vc deu. Para ter uma solução completa, sugiro compartilhar a base de dados ou uma parte dela.

Answer (score 2):

Além da resposta do [Lucas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/136394/lucas) (que eu até prefiro), você pode manter a base do seu código

Criando o data frame de teste

```
import pandas as pd
dados = ["35,57B", "6,85T"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dados': dados})
df
```

Mostrando o data frame

```
     Dados
0   35,57B
1    6,85T
```

Adicionei um replace a mais e no regex coloquei uma virgula no lugar do ponto, o astype mudei pra int nas duas condições

```
df['Dados'] = df['Dados'].str.replace(',','').replace(r'[KMBT]+$', '', regex=True).astype('int64') * df['Dados'].str.extract(r'[\d\,]+([KMBT]+)', expand = False).replace(['K','M','B','T'], [10**3, 10**6, 10**9, 10**12]).astype('int64')
```

Caso queira salvar como string

```
df['Dados'] = df['Dados'].astype(str)
```

Saída:

```
0      3557000000000
1    685000000000000
```

Comment: Boa Tarde!
Estava tentando fazer a sua solução de modo iterativa, acabei caindo no mesmo problema q já tive antes. O code ficaria algo do tipo:
```for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',','').replace(r'[KMBT]+$', '', regex=True).astype('int64') * df[col].str.extract(r'[\d\,]+([KMBT]+)', expand = False).replace(['K','M','B','T'], [10**3, 10**6, 10**9, 10**12]).astype('int64')```
Porém a minha primeira coluna do df é uma de código, a qual eu não queria iterar sobre. Sabe oq posso fazer para que esse for comece na primeira coluna, ao invés da coluna 0?

Comment: @Dataworm1523,  boa tarde! `for col in df.columns.drop(['Coluna_que_você_não_deseja']):` Acho que algo assim funcionaria